# Merging columns while adding rows of two tables

Tags: bash, join

I want to merge two tables which contain identical row headers `A`, `B`, etc, and a number of column headers `a`, `b`, etc. that overlap only partially. I need to merge the tables so that matching columns are merged, but the rows are added.

Example:

Table 1

```
   a    b    c    d
A  1    NA   3    2
B  NA   NA   1    3 
C  2    3    NA   NA
D  NA   5    NA   1
```

Table 2

```
   a    d    e    f
A  NA   1    3    NA
B  NA   1    NA   2
C  4    NA   3    NA
D  1    NA   NA   2
```

resulting table

```
   a    b    c    d    e    f
A  1    NA   3    2    NA   NA
A  NA   NA   NA   1    3    NA
B  NA   NA   1    3    NA   NA
B  NA   NA   NA   1    NA   2
C  2    3    NA   NA   NA   NA
C  4    NA   NA   NA   3    NA
D  NA   5    NA   1    NA   NA
D  1    NA   NA   NA   NA   2
```

The columns and rows do not need to be sorted in any special order. I played around with the `join` command, but it requires sorted files, which my data is somehow not. When I try a variant of

```
join <(sort file1.txt) <(sort file2.txt)
```

I get different results where some part (or all) of the data is removed. The NA strings can be replaced by some other placeholder if that makes the task easier.